# Progress Bar compatibility API 16 thru 23

Tags: android

Sorry ... newbie here. This method works great for my intended purposes but the progress bar will not close after loading on API lower than 21. So the title bar displays the name of the activity and Loading and it looks like crap. Is there a method to force close of the progress bar on the lower API's? Thanks for your time.

```
final Activity WebActivity = this;
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            WebActivity .setTitle("Loading...");
            WebActivity .setProgress(progress * 100);
            if(progress == 100)
                WebActivity .setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
        }
    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("Website URL");
```

Comment: A window's `ProgressBar` was deprecated in API Level 21 IIRC and is discontinued in API Level 24. I recommend that you put your own `ProgressBar` into your layout.

Comment: thanks for the info. wasn't sure of the exact API because I don't have a API 20 virtual device.